# UITableView allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing for single section?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

Is it possible to use the allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing property of a UITableView and have it apply to only 1 of several sections in a UITableView?

Answer (score 1):

Yup!

see this delegate method

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```